# How can my code structure be improved?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, algorithms, class-design

I am looking for advice on the neatest way to structure my code.

```
class Password
{
    private string cipher;

    Password(string cipher)
    {
        this.cipher = cipher;
    }

    public string HashPassword()
    {

    }

    public bool VerifyPassword()
    {

    }
}
```

The idea behind the class is to abstract away the password hashing process. The class will present two functions to the user, `HashPassword()` and `VerifyPassword()`, which will perform completely different hashing algorithms depending on the value of the `cipher` variable.

Currently, I am using a set of `if/else` conditional statements within the two functions itself to determine which hashing algorithm to perform. However, it felt quite inelegant to me.

Is there a better way of structuring my code?

Comment: there is a [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1) for this

Comment: @ratchetfreak, note that to be on topic for us over on Code Review you'd really need to show actual code, not just an outline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a base class - `PasswordHasher` or such that will be abstract (or, if you find that implementation vary too much for implementations to share anything, use an interface).

From it, inherit a class for each hash algorithm you are going to use.

Using dependency injection, you can use either algorithm by simply passing in the relevant class.